# FIFO queue with one pointer

Tags: java, queue

So hello everybody , I wrote a fifo queue implementation in java with 2 pointers (head,tail). I would like to know if is there any way to create a fifo circular queue that uses only the head pointer.Any suggestion is appreciated.

My code is the following :

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.*

public class StringQueueImpl<T> implements StringQueue {

private int total;         // number of elements on queue
private Node head;    // beginning of queue
private Node tail;     // end of queue

private class Node {
    T ele;
    Node next;
    Node(T ele) {
    this.ele = ele;
    next = null; } 
} 
 /**
 * Creates an empty queue.
 */
public StringQueueImpl() {
    first = null;
    last  = null;
    total = 0;
}

boolean isEmpty() {
    return (head == null); 
}

public <T> void put(T ele) {
    Node t = tail;
    tail = new Node(ele);
    if (isEmpty()) head = tail;
    else t.next = tail; 
    total++;
} 

public T get() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    T v = head.ele;
    Node t = head.next;
    head = t;
    return v; 
    total--;
} 


public T peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return head.ele;
}

Node node = head; 
public void printQueue(PrintStream stream){
    while(node != null){
        stream.println(node.ele);
        stream.flush();
        node = node.next;
    }
}

public int size(){
    return total;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test everything but some functions are working.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Queue;


public class CircularQueue<T> implements Queue<T> {

    private Node head = null;
    private Integer size = 0;

    private class Node{
        private Node next;
        private T data;

        public Node() {
        }

        public Node(T data,Node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int size() {
        return this.size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(null == head)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        Node temp = head;
        int counter = 0 ;
        while(counter < size){
            if(temp.data.equals(o)){
                return true;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
            counter++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        if(isEmpty())
            return null;
        Object[] arr = new Object[size];
        Node temp = head;
        int counter = 0 ;
        while(counter < size){
            arr[counter] = temp.data;
            counter++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        Node temp = head;
        int counter = 0 ;
        while(counter < size){
            a[counter] = (T) temp.data;
            counter++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        if(isEmpty())
            return false;

        if(size() == 1){
            size--;
            if(head.data.equals(o))
                head = head.next;
            return true;
        }


        Node temp = head;
        int counter = 1;
        while(counter < size){
            if(o.equals(temp.next.data)){
                temp = temp.next.next;
                size--;
                return true;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
            counter ++;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        if(isEmpty())
            return false;
        Iterator<?> it = c.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            if(!contains(it.next())){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        Iterator<? extends T> it = c.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){            
            add(it.next());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        Iterator<?> it = c.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){            
            remove(it.next());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        head = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T e) {

        if(isEmpty()){
            head = new Node();
            head.next = head;
            head.data = e;
            size++;
            return true;
        }

        if(size() == 1){
            Node temp = new Node();
            temp.data = e;
            temp.next = head;
            head.next = temp;
            size++;
            return true;
        }

        Node temp = head;
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < size - 1){
            counter++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        temp.next = new Node(e,head);
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(T e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public T remove() {
        if(isEmpty())
            return null;

        Node temp = head;
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < size){
            temp = temp.next;
            counter++;
        }
        head = head.next;
        temp.next = head;

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T poll() {
        if(isEmpty())
            return null;

        if(size() == 1){
            T data = head.data;
            head = null;
            size--;
            return data;
        }
        T data = head.data;

        Node temp = head;
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < size - 1){
            counter++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        head = head.next;
        temp.next = head;
        size--;
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public T element() {
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue is Empty!!!");
        T data = head.data;
        head = head.next;
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public T peek() {
        return head.data;
    }

    public void print(){
        Node temp = head;
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < size){
            counter++;
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp = temp.next;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircularQueue<String> circularQueue = new CircularQueue<>();

        if(circularQueue.isEmpty()){
            circularQueue.add("Gurkan");
            circularQueue.print();
            circularQueue.add("Illeez");
            circularQueue.print();
            circularQueue.add("Test1");
            circularQueue.print();
            circularQueue.add("Test2");
            circularQueue.print();
            while(!circularQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println(circularQueue.poll());
            }
        }

    }

}
```